# Take text-value from each row in a listview adapter, where checkbox is checked

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using a custom listview with a textview and a checkbox side by side.
How can take textview value from each one row where checkbox is checked?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:weightSum="100"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="First Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtName" />
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my ListViewAdapter

```
 class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Person>
{
    public List<Person> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Person> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Person this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);

        }
        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName);
        txtName.Text = mitems[position].FirstName;

        CheckBox txtCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtCheckBox);
        txtCheckBox.Text = mitems[position].CheckBox;



        //SetOnCheckedChangeListener must be set before txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked
        txtCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(position, ref mitems));
        txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked;
        Console.WriteLine("Set the CheckBox " + position + " to " + mitems[position].IsChecked);

        return row;
    }

    public class CheckChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        int position;
        List<Person> items;
        public CheckChangeListener(int position, ref List<Person> items)
        {
            this.position = position;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {
            items[position].IsChecked = isChecked;
            Console.WriteLine("Set the " + position + " IsChecked to " + isChecked);
        }
    }
```

This is my class

```
 class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string CheckBox { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code in my main activity

```
  public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private List<Person> mItems;
    private ListView mlistview;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

        mItems = new List<Person>();

        mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "test1" });
        mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "test2" });
        mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "test3" });
        mItems.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "test4" });

        MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);

        mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
```

How can with a button to add all my checked checkboxes FirstName into a String?

Comment: On your CheckChangeListener u set value to IsChecked on Person instance and TextView.Text is initalized with Person.FirstName. So when u need text from Persons which are checked use Linq : mItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.FirstName);

Comment: It asks to Convert it as string.So i convert it as string but i take this result:   System.Linq.Enumerable+whereSelectListlterator'2(App1.Person.System.String]

Comment: U know what is IEnumerable ?